# Should Kubernetes operator delete resources which are not managed by it?

Tags: kubernetes

I have my application deployed on Kubernetes cluster, managed by operator (A). I am mounting secrets with ssl key materials to the deployment, so application could access to the content.

I have separate operator (B) deployment, which is responsible to create those secrets with the ssl key materials. Now I have a use case where my secrets are recreated by operator (B), and it deletes/restarts the pods, which managed by operator (A).

I am trying understand - **is it common practice to allow separately deployed operator delete pods?**

My perception was that operator should work only with resources it manages, nothing more.

Comment: That would also usually be my understanding.  Note that the essence of the Kubernetes controller model is that the controller looks at the current state of the Kubernetes configuration store (not changes or events, just which objects exist and which don't) and tries to make the things it manages match that, so if the controller believes it should manage some external resource and there's not a matching Kubernetes object, it could delete it.  Do you have a more concrete example of a case where it goes wrong?

Comment: Yes I understand concept of state and desired state. My point is that operator B, which created new secret, programmatically deleting pods, which are managed by operator A, so the new pods could get the new content of the secret.

Comment: That sort of seems like a bug...but also, Pods are pretty disposable and the usual expectation is that a ReplicaSet or another controller will recreate them...?  It'd help if you could clarify the question with specific code, since I don't think there's a clear yes-or-no answer to what you're asking currently.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I am not sure you can reproduce. Both operators are proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki to summarise the topic.

If it is as you say:

> both operators are proprietary,

it is impossible to give a definite yes or no answer. Everything will depend on what is really going on there, and we are not able to check and evaluate it.

Look at the well provided comments by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze):

> That sort of seems like a bug...but also, Pods are pretty disposable and the usual expectation is that a ReplicaSet or another controller will recreate them...?

> Note that the essence of the Kubernetes controller model is that the controller looks at the current state of the Kubernetes configuration store (not changes or events, just which objects exist and which don't) and tries to make the things it manages match that, so if the controller believes it should manage some external resource and there's not a matching Kubernetes object, it could delete it.